# converting and priniting LCS palindrome with minimum insertions

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am working on a algorithm converting string to palindrome with minimum insertions. I found the LCS approach most understandable (http://isharemylearning.blogspot.com/2012/08/minimum-number-of-insertions-in-string.html) and plenty of implementation can be found to calculate the number but almost no mention as how to generate the actual palindrome. I couldn't figure out the way to generate the result based on backtracking the LCS scoring matrix, particularly when only insertion is allowed. If someone can help me out, that would be great.

Comment: There are potentially many ways to turn a string into a palindrome, all with the same number of insertions. Consider the string 'ABBC'. You can turn it to 'ACBBCA' or 'CABBAC'. Does it help?

Comment: thanks. I understand that but I have difficulty to generate any palindrome based on the LCS score

Comment: You need not only score but the actual LCS as well. Take a string, find the LCS, and paint the corresponding characters red. Run two pointers through the string from both ends towards each other until they meet. When two pointers point at (identical) red characters, move them both. Otherwise you need to insert a character and then move the pointers. Does this make sense?

Comment: maybe an example would help